# Running Terraform apply aws_ecs_task_definition fails with Error: ClientException: Role is not valid

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

When I run Terraform apply I get this cryptic error message and I can't figure out how to resolve it.

```
$  terraform apply "cms-container.plan"
aws_ecs_task_definition.dev-cms_task: Creating...

Error: ClientException: Role is not valid

  on ecs.tf line 19, in resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "dev-cms_task":
  19: resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "dev-cms_task" {
```

Below is the code definition that I am using.

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "dev-cms_task" {
    family                   = var.ecs_task_family
    container_definitions    = data.template_file.container_definition.rendered
    cpu                      = var.ecs_task_cpu
    memory                   = var.ecs_task_memory
    network_mode             = "awsvpc"
    requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
    task_role_arn            = "arn:aws:iam::<account #>:role/FargateTaskRole"
    execution_role_arn       = "arn:aws:iam::<account #>:role/Fargate-ECSTaskExecutionRole"

    tags = var.resource_tags
}
```

System Details:

- Terraform version: 1.0.5
- OS: Windows 10

I have tried different versions of terraform and I have also tried using roles from a remote state file.

Role Policy Definition:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ecs.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share the role definition including the trust policy for each of the roles you're trying to attach please?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR  - the roles that you see in the code sample are existing roles which were not created through terraform. The roles were created through the console, some time ago before we started using terraform. So unfortunately I don't have a role definition for them. I have added the trust policy to the post.

Answer (score 1):

For both the [task role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html#create_task_iam_policy_and_role) and the [task execution role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_execution_IAM_role.html) the service that needs to be trusted is `ecs-task.amazonaws.com` rather than `ecs.amazonaws.com`.

So your trust relationship (or [`assume_role_policy`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role#assume_role_policy) in Terraform's [`aws_iam_role`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role) needs to look like this:

```json
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

The `ecs.amazonaws.com` service is reserved for when ECS as a service needs to do things such as with the [service-linked role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using-service-linked-roles.html).

Comment: ydaetskcoR - thank you for your suggestions, I updated the policy statement as per your suggestion and I am still getting the same error.